# Improve performance of query with multiple joins

Tags: sql, performance

I have a query with four joins that is taking a considerable amount of time to execute. Is there a way to optimize the query? I tried to include the smaller `PORTFOLIO` table on the joins to try speeding up the process.

```
SELECT
    A.*
  , B.REPORTING_PERIOD
  , D.HPI AS CURRENT_HPI
  , E.USSWAP10
  , B.DLQ_STATUS AS CURRENT_STATUS
  , C.DLQ_STATUS AS NEXT_STATUS
FROM PORTFOLIO A
JOIN ALL_PERFORMANCE B ON
  A.AGENCY = B.AGENCY 
  AND A.LOAN_ID = B.LOAN_ID
JOIN ALL_PERFORMANCE C ON
  A.AGENCY = C.AGENCY
  AND A.LOAN_ID = C.LOAN_ID 
  AND DATEADD(MONTH, 1, B.REPORTING_PERIOD) = C.REPORTING_PERIOD
LEFT JOIN CASE_SHILLER D ON 
  A.GEO_CODE = D.GEO_CODE 
  AND B.REPORTING_PERIOD = D.AS_OF_DATE
LEFT JOIN SWAP_10Y E ON 
  B.REPORTING_PERIOD = E.AS_OF_DATE
```

Comment: Look at your tables an control,w hich indexes are set.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Some information will be useful: a) database system and its version, b) definitions of tables, c) example of data. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for inspiration. Help community to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can index the columns you join on

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have indexes for the combinations of joins you are using to increase performance. Thesee are the indexes you should have:

- Index on (PORTFOLIO.AGENCY, PORTFOLIO.LOAN_ID)
- Index on (ALL_PERFORMANCE.AGENCY, ALL_PERFORMANCE.LOAN_ID)
- Index on ALL_PERFORMANCE.REPORTING_PERIOD
- Index on (ALL_PERFORMANCE.AGENCY, ALL_PERFORMANCE.LOAN_ID, ALL_PERFORMANCE.REPORTING_PERIOD)
- Index on (CASE_SHILLER.GEO_CODE, CASE_SHILLER.AS_OF_DATE)
- Index on PORTFOLIO.GEO_CODE
- Index on ALL_PERFORMANCE.REPORTING_PERIOD
- Index on SWAP_10Y.AS_OF_DATE
- Index on ALL_PERFORMANCE.REPORTING_PERIOD